# Commercial analog to digital converters using sub nyquist sampling rate

Tags: adc

Are there any commercial analog-to-digital converters (ADC) that use a sub-nyquist sampling rate, i.e., exploit the theory of compressed sensing in order to sample using a data rate that is smaller than the nyquist rate.

Comment: What do you mean by "commercial"? They are all commercial. Also ADCs are sampling momentary values, and you can program your application to sample at any rate and process the data according to the desired algorithm.

Comment: Basically all of them.

Comment: I think you mean sub-Nyquist Compression+Sampling = Xampling  as in DivX video compression or  maybe a bank of time staggered sub-Nyquist track/Hold ADC's

Comment: remember how sub-sampling Scopes work for xx GHz response

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, you're right. I don't know how DivX compression works, but I was thinking of the Xampling as described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.2495.pdf).

Comment: @EugeneSh., Commercial in contrast to some implementations described in some research papers.

Answer (score 4):

*Any* ADC (as long as it doesn't integrate an anti-aliasing filter itself) can be operated sub-Nyquist. That's not a property of the ADC, but of the way you're using it.

Comment: And if you want *the signal* to behave as if it is being under-sampled, then you want a *low-pass filter* in front of the ADC.

Comment: I think the Op has something else entirely different in mind with Compression+Sampling = Xampling where 
X prefix for compression, e.g. DivX  for sub-Nyquist sampling rates

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, Right!

Comment: Then you had better be more specific !

Comment: @Likely skimming that paper: what you need are mixers and ADCs, both of which are commercially available, even in integrated form. Again, the fact that you want to do Xampling with these is not a property of the ADC or mixer, but your way of using it! So, my answer still stands.

Comment: I think his question didn't ask for what he wanted. The implementations have "a lot" more processes than ADC.  e.g. h.265 video encoder